# React generic set hooks function that works on several hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to make a function that returns a clear icon to a input field in React Native.
I had a idea to send a click event to the icon since that is the one that  will handle the click, but how can I make the function take in a hook setter and execute the passed code?

Ex: if the clear icon for mail is clicked, set mail hook value: "", and same but with the mail input. Code below will generate a infinite loop

```
const [mail, setMail] = useState({ value: "", placeholder: "E-mail" })
const [password, setPassword] = useState({ value: "", placeholder: "Password" })

const clearIcon = (props: { setHook??: any }) => {  
    if (props.value.length > 0) {            
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.setHook()}> //Must work dynamically for all hooks
                    <MaterialIcons name="clear" size={30} color={Colors.themeWhite} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )                        
    }

    else
        return (
            <AntDesign name="mail" size={30} color="transparent" />
        )
}

 <Input
     value={mail.value}
     ...
     rightIcon={clearIcon({sethook: setMail({...mail, value: ""})})}
 />
 <Input
     value={password.value}
     ...
     rightIcon={clearIcon({sethook: setPassword({...password, value: ""})})}
 />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `ClearIcon` as a component

```
const ClearIcon = (props: { setHook: any }) => {
  return props.value.length > 0 ? (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.setHook()}>
      {" "}
      //Must work dynamically for all hooks
      <MaterialIcons name="clear" size={30} color={Colors.themeWhite} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ) : (
    <AntDesign name="mail" size={30} color="transparent" />
  );
};
```

Update your Input component to accept rightIcon as a function which return a Componet, Then use it in input

```
<Input
     value={mail.value}
     ...
     rightIcon={() => <ClearIcon sethook={() => setMail({...mail, value: ""})}/>}
 />
 <Input
     value={password.value}
     ...
     rightIcon={() => <ClearIcon sethook={() => setPassword({...password, value: ""})}/>}
 />
```